# GitHub, Linux Server and Ownership Issues

Tags: linux, git, github, laravel-4, ownership

I've got a private Git repo on GitHub and I have setup SSH connections between my server and github.com. I can pull my app from GitHub successfully on to the server but when I visit my app URL I get a '500 Internal Server Error'. My host suggests that this is to do with ownership problems.

So my question is this, if I am logged in to my server via SSH as root, and I do a pull request, how can I make sure that the ownership of the files on the server are correct.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think git ever changes ownership, does it? So the files will end up being owned by root unless you `chown -R ` them afterwards. Can your application server read files that are owned by root? Do you have access to the server error logs so you can see exactly what the 500 was?

Comment: Can you view the site, if you exec : `chown -R example:example /var/www/example.com/*`, where example is the webserver user/group or the SuexecUserGroup, maybe additional chmod's `chmod --recursive  755 /var/www/example.com/` after git pull? What's in the server (or suexec?) log?

Comment: I get this in the log [warn] File "/home/purple/public_html/cream/public/index.php" is writeable by group

Comment: And that breaks it even though it's a "[warn]"? To remove group write for all files do `chmod -R g-w /home/purple/public_html/cream` - you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Not sure it's that, that is breaking it but it's the only reference to cream in the logs.

Comment: Yeah, I did sorry. It says this in the logs now [warn] UID of script "/home/purple/public_html/cream/public/index.php" is smaller than min_uid

Comment: I've done chown -R root:root cream and I still get the 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Right - it's not letting you leave the files owned by root then. What user is the web server running as? Can you chown the files to that? Or to purple?

Comment: It's all sorted. Not sure how it was fixed as the server tech guys did it.